# How to convert whole page to docx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a task of creating a sort of form that needs to be downloadable. I am using reactjs to render a html page, and now i need a way to convert that page to .docx file. Any ideas? If you also have some easy way of converting page to pdf, that would be great as well, but i can already do that, albeit via long process, so my primary goal is docx.

Comment: This is the read the specs idea: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-docx/b839fe1f-e1ca-4fa6-8c26-5954d0abbccd

Comment: @Estradiaz i meant something more like a library/plugin etc that will "do the work for me"

Comment: i was sure you googled docx react and the first result doesnt work - but nvm

Comment: I did. Howere, the first result is about generating docx, rather than converting page. But i guess, i will have to use it if i dont find some more practical solution

Comment: Thanks for your question! I am going through same thing and hope to find something helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There is a library named `redox` which may be useful for your situation. It explained itself as:

> `redocx` is a library which lets you create word documents with React.
>   It provides a set of components which renders your declarative views
>   and components to word documents.

[View on GitHub](https://github.com/nitin42/redocx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will check it out